# Changing the date format VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a date column that look like this:

> 04-03-2013 01:57:32 PM IST

I am trying to change it to look like this:

> 04/03/2013  13:57:32

my code:

```
Columns("D:E").Select 
Selection.Replace What:=" IST", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:=" IDT", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

Selection.Replace What:="-", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

the problome is that it change it to look like that:

> 04-03-2013 01:57:32 PM

and only when I press manually ENTER after "PM" it changes to:

> 04/03/2013  13:57:32

How can i do it automatically?

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to specify the desired number format:

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" 
' or mm/dd/yyyy, not sure which you want!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the original dates to "real" Excel dates that are formatted as above, then try, in a regular module:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ChangeDateTimeFormat()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim C As Range
Set Rng = Range("D:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
For Each C In Rng
    With C
        If Right(.Text, 4) = " IDT" Or Right(.Text, 4) = " IST" Then
            .Value = DateValue(Left(.Text, Len(.Text) - 4)) + TimeValue(Left(.Text, Len(.Text) - 4))
            .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
        End If
    End With
Next C
End Sub
```

This was only tested with dates in MDY format.  If your dates are in DMY format, and this doesn't work, I will test further.